# ASP.NET Core CORS middleware doesn't return all headers in Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

Im using ASP.NET Core with `UseCors()`.

How do I get it to list all headers specified in `WithHeaders()` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`? In particular, I want it to return the `Accept` and `Origin` headers, but it doesnt.

If I set:

```
builder.WithHeaders("Content-Type","Accept","Origin");
```

Or even

```
builder.AllowAnyHeader();
```

And then do an OPTIONS request with

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, Origin
```

I still get back only

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Is there a way to tell the Cors middleware to return all of them?

I know they are not required according to the spec, but I have buggy clients (Safari 6 and 7) that need them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like this :

```
app.UseCors(
            builder => builder.WithHeaders("Content-Type,Accept,codeVersion,login-email,login-password,language,Content-Encoding,Authorization".Trim().Split(",").ToArray())
);
```

Comment: No. I might be missing something, but I can't see why that would help?

Comment: i'm using that configuration and its working for me : i'm using asp.net core 2.1 and Angular 6

Comment: I just tested it and it does not work. Are you running this configuration publicly somewhere where I can try it out?

Comment: this exactly what i'm using in my configuration :
app.UseCors(
                builder => builder
               .WithOrigins(Tool.GetListAuthorizedCustomers().ToArray())
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .WithHeaders("Content-Type,Accept,codeVersion,login-email,login-password,language,Content-Encoding,Authorization".Trim().Split(",").ToArray())
               .AllowCredentials()
            );

Comment: And this makes the web server return "Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept" header when the client sends an OPTION request with "Access-Control-Request-Headers:Accept"?

Comment: Yes, otherwise your request cannot be sent.

Comment: Sure it can. The "Accept" header is by default allowed, so most clients do not require it to be explicitly allowed by the server. If you're sure that it is returned from your server then there must be something else differing between our configurations, because I can't get it to work.